# when to use CABasicAnimation and CAKeyFrameAnimation and CGAffineTransform?

Tags: cgaffinetransform, cakeyframeanimation, cabasicanimation

when to use CABasicAnimation and CAKeyFrameAnimation and CGAffineTransform?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**CABasicAnimation** 
: provides basic, single-keyframe animation capabilities for a layer property.

**CAKeyFrameAnimation**:CAKeyframeAnimation provides generic keyframe animation capabilities for a layer property in the render tree.

**CGAffineTransform:**
The CGAffineTransform data structure represents a matrix used for affine transformations. A transformation specifies how points in one coordinate system map to points in another coordinate system. An affine transformation is a special type of mapping that preserves parallel lines in a path but does not necessarily preserve lengths or angles. Scaling, rotation, and translation are the most commonly used manipulations supported by affine transforms, but skewing is also possible.

For more read [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html)

Comment: Unfortunately the link is now broken.